# Can this Non-Linear Residual Function, $R(x)=((x+1)^3-1)^{1/3}-(x+1)$, be expressed exactly using an Infinite Series or Polynomial Function in $x$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, approximation

Can this Non-Linear Residual Function, $R(x)=((x+1)^3-1)^{1/3}-(x+1)$, be expressed exactly using a infinite series (using integer powers in $x$) or a finite polynomial function in $x$?

For example I have found one approximate series / polynomial function that is a reasonably accurate approximation above $x=2$

$$R(x) \approx -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{3 (x+1)^{2n}}=-\frac{1}{3(x^2+2x+2)}$$

Can you please give some advice in how I might proceed with this problem?

Is the method to proceed using the calculus of finite differences to improve the approximation I have obtained or is there some direct transformation I can apply?

**Update Added 13/02/2024**

Just playing around tonight I've been able to produce a better approximation, i.e.

$$R(x) \approx -\frac{1}{3 (x+1)^2}-\frac{1}{9 (x+1)^5}-\frac{1}{17 (x+1)^8}-\frac{1}{18 (x+1)^{11}}$$

Which is semi-regular but the trial and error iteration technique seems to run out of steam in terms of improving accuracy with increasing number of terms.

Maybe @GregMartin's answer is telling me this, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

$R(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, so there's no analytic function that will match it exactly. However, $R(x)$ does have a [Puiseux series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series) at $x=0$ that will converge for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: I really want to understand the constraints/limitations on regular semi-regular approximation series like the one I've now added to my question above. Although I am very appreciative of your answer, just a proof that no analytic function will exactly match $R(x)$ seems a little too vague to me as an answer to this question. I feel there is more depth to a problem such as this to be uncovered - but maybe that is a research question.

Comment: Near $x=0$ the function is asymptotic to a constant times $x^{-1/3}$, so there's no way of avoiding that if we want good approximations near $0$. I'm not sure why you've chosen an approximation using negative powers of $x+1$; that could conceivably give a good approximation when $x$ is far from $-1$, but certainly not close to $-1$. Perhaps you have a particular range of $x$ that's important for you?—if so, that's worth adding to the question.